# running package.json in docker with reference to a private repository vsts git repository fails due to authentication failure

Tags: node.js, git, docker, azure-devops

My main project has package.json which has dependencies with another private VSTS Git repository

```
"dependencies": {
    "sk-api": "git+ssh://My-tfs@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:22/tk-api/_ssh/tk-api#v1.1.7",
    "sk-modes": "git+ssh://My-tfs@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:22/tk-modes/_ssh/tk-modes#tk"
  },
```

In my desktop i have installed the SSH key so when I run `npm install` it works. But when i run `docker build` through my docker file it fails due to authentication.

> npm ERR! Host key verification failed. npm ERR! fatal: Could not read
>   from remote repository.

```
FROM node:boron

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Set env
ENV PORT 3000

# Install app dependencies
ADD package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN cd /tmp && npm install

# Bundle app source
ADD . /usr/src/app

# Open port to access server
EXPOSE $PORT
# Execute as bash script to pass along env variables
CMD npm start
```

What is the best way to go about this. Should also copy the ssh key in the docker file before running npm install?

Comment: Have you added the SSH key to your VSTS account?

Comment: yes I have added SSH key to my VSTS account and when I do npm install from my computer it works.  The dockerfile has npm install command when I do "docker build" it tries to execute package.json which in turn tried to call the other repositories and fails. For testing I put the ssh key I use inside the image build then it work but I feel this is not a good practice.

Comment: It's necessary to specify the SSH key into dockerfile. Else there will have authentication problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To troubleshooting the issue, please check with below aspects:

1. Make sure the SSH Key has been added to the VSTS account
2. Make sure the SSH Key also provided in the docker image.

   You can commit the SSH Key into your git repo in a file, and then copy the file (SSH Key) to your docker image. You can refer the gist [npm install from private repo, in docker build](https://gist.github.com/eschwartz/8518b21d5d2854d8a4f7c7e7507f0561) for detail steps.

---

There is no way to restrict SSH key only with read permission. But you can use **personal access token** (PAT) to achieve (use HTTP protocol instead of SSH protocol). Details as below:

1. Create a PAT only with Code (read) scope selected

   [image]
2. Use PAT in git repo URL

   Use the URL format as:

   `git+https://Personal%20Access%20Token:PAT@account.visualstudio.com/project/_git/repo`

   Such as you can change the dependencies in your package.json file as:

   ```
   "dependencies": {
       "sk-api": "git+https://Personal%20Access%20Token:adsvso24n1nd6o7vydn3hsfvb5nicrqrbjm5umwrxnktglemajta@My-tfs.visualstudio.com/tk-api/_git/tk-api ",
       "sk-modes": "git+https://Personal%20Access%20Token:adsvso24n1nd6o7vydn3hsfvb5nicrqrbjm5umwrxnktglemajta@My-tfs.visualstudio.com/tk-modes/_git/tk-modes "
     },
   ```

Comment: the second point is what I doing but is there a way to restrict the permissions for the ssh like only have read access.

Comment: To authen only with read premission, you can use PAT instead. I added it in the end of the answer, you can have a try.